# How to tell if an iPhone is hacked and how to prevent it?

Tags: iphone, hacking

A friend of mine said he thinks his iPhone has been hacked. How do you find out if it has been and *more importantly* how do you stop it?

He called me up because his girlfriend says things during fights that he mentioned in text messages. He said she let it slip she ‘remoted’ in to his phone.

I think I know one way this could have happened. If she backed up his phone to her Macbook then iMessage on her computer might be receiving his messages. But that would only work if she has a Mac unless there is an iMessage for Windows.

Comment: tell your friend to leave his girlfriend and change his apple ID

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really know why people always think their device is being hacked after something *weird* is happening in their eyes.

If she made a backup on a computer, and someone put that version back - they have access to the complete iPhone after restoring it on another device. Can this be the case?

If not, he said things during fights on iMessage? Maybe he just said it and regret it afterwards claiming he didn't send it. I don't see why anyone would add extra text to a fight and not use it for something else (if they really have bad intentions.)

Backing up an iPhone to a Mac does not turn on iMessage by default unless the user activates this him/herself. It is impossible to get active just because of a backup.

**Solution**
Change the Apple ID password and all default Apple services will become useless because it will prompt for the new password.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know. I'm trying to find out more details but I'll pass it on changing the Apple ID password.

Comment: He has a PC and she has a Mac. So if iMessage doesn't automatically activate then it might be she might just know his password or something.

Comment: It's possible she has activated Messages.app on her Mac using his Apple ID, and she's reading his iMessages.

Comment: Turns out she knew his password! Change your passwords people!